# Stream incremental file uploads off of GCS into Kafka

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-storage, apache-flink

I'm working with a pipeline that pushes JSON entries in batches to my Gcloud Storage bucket. I want to get this data into Kafka.

The way I'm going about it now is using a lambda function that gets triggered every minute to find the files that have changed, open streams from them, read line by line and batch every so often those lines as messages into a kafka producer.

This process is pretty terrible, but it works.... eventually.

I was hoping there'd be a way to do this w/ Kafka Connect or Flink, but there really isn't much development around sensing incremental file additions to a bucket.

Comment: How frequently are the files actually changing? Can the lambda be changed to only run when file modifications are detected rather than "every minute"?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Files come in every second. Up to 5000 files a second.

Comment: How large are they? There is nothing that can be done before they are written to GCS to batch those events?

Comment: They are about 0.5MB -1MB each. They can't be batched from the push side anymore, any batching I have to do after they are in the bucket.

Comment: Based on my experience, sounds like you might want to consider changing to something like "Delta Lake" or Apache Hudi rather than raw GCS filesystem

Comment: @OneCricketeer Databricks has an out of the box solution on their delta lake called AutoLoader--but unfortunately will have to get the hacky solution first.

Answer (score 1):

Do the JSON entries end up in different files in your bucket? Flink has support for streaming in new files from a source.

Comment: I think a lambda would be "better" in terms of cost rather than a long-running Flink job that watches the bucket

Comment: Yes different files, and they are named with a timestamp to the millisecond. Up to 5000 files are uploaded ever  1 second batch.